# Javascript to export HTML table to Excel - Add options

Tags: javascript

I have the following piece of code which exports my table to Excel:

```
<script>
var tableToExcel = (function() {
  var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'

    , template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">'

+ '<head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>'
+ '<x:ExcelWorkbook>'
+ '<x:ExcelWorksheets>'
+ '<x:ExcelWorksheet>'
+ '<x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name>'
+ '<x:WorksheetOptions>'
+ '<x:DisplayGridlines/>'
+ '</x:WorksheetOptions>'
+ '<ProtectObjects>False</ProtectObjects>'
+ '<ProtectScenarios>False</ProtectScenarios>'
+ '</x:ExcelWorksheet>'

// + '<Header x:Data="&amp;CTHIS IS THE HEADER (CENTER)"/>'
// + '<Footer x:Data="&amp;RTHIS IS THE FOOTER (RIGHT)"/>'
// + '<Layout x:Orientation="Landscape" x:CenterHorizontal="1"/>'

+ '</x:ExcelWorksheets>'
+ '</x:ExcelWorkbook>'
+ '</xml>'
+ '<![endif]-->'
+ '</head>'
+ '<body>'
+ '<table border=1>{table}</table>'
+ '</body>'
+ '</html>'

    , base64 = function(s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
    , format = function(s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) { return c[p]; }) }
  return function(table, name) {
    if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table)
    var ctx = {worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: table.innerHTML}
    window.location.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx))
  }
})()
</script>
```

I have two issues:

**Issue the First:** The 3 lines that are commented out do not seem to take effect anywhere I place them. If I can get these options implemented, that would be outstanding. (Yes, I realize I must un-comment them to work...)

**Issue the Second:** When exporting the table, the filename ends up as `whatever.xls.XLS`. I'm not sure how the extension is being duplicated.

Please help.

Comment: Works well for me: https://jsfiddle.net/dannyjhonston/o86w33ru/.

Comment: Yes, it exports to Excel just fine but the file export: 1) Isn't Landscape, 2) Doesn't have titles, and 3) Still has two extensions (.xls.xls)